# WPF control properties set in 'code behind', after that binding is ignored

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, code-behind

I'm really new in WPF. I tried to set a default value for a control-property in code and want to overwrite the property by data binding, when the datacontext (VM) is available. But the databinding is not working in this case.

Example:

code behind:

> ```
> public partial class MyViewControl : UserControl
> {
>     public MyViewControl()
>     {
>         InitializeComponent();
>         // it works if I remove this line
>         panelControl.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
>     }
> }
> ```

xaml usercontrol:

```
<DockPanel Name="panelControl" Visibility="{Binding
MyViewModelProperty_IsVisible_ConvertedToVisibility}">
```

xaml mainwindow:

```
<my:MyViewControl DataContext="{Binding  ElementName=lbListBox,
Path=SelectedItem}"/>
```

Actually the FallbackValue parameter works for this scenario, but I want to know the technical reason, why the control property cannot be bound after it was set by code?

Comment: *cannot be bound **after** it was set by code* - not really after, binding occurs somewhere in `InitializeComponent` (**before** you overwrite it), in your code you simply overwrite the binding after it was set (means no binding anymore). Try setting binding again after that line. The question is why are you doing that?

Comment: Initially I tried to set a default value. But I have already found the **FallbackValue** parameter which is working for this purpose. So the question rose up to understand how the framework works ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Xaml is processed during `InitializeComponent()`, so this is what is happening:

```
InitializeComponent(); // binding is set
panelControl.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden; // binding is removed (value is set)
```

You can restore binding

```
InitializeComponent();
panelControl.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
BindingOperations.SetBinding(panelControl, Control.VisibilityProperty,
    new Binding()
{
    Path = new PropertyPath(nameof(ViewModel.MyViewModelProperty_IsVisible_ConvertedToVisibility)),
    Source = viewModelInstance, // this.DataContext ?
});
```

And it will work after. But it's not really clear why do you want to overwrite binding in first place.

Comment: got it, a property-binding will be removed, if the prorty-value is changed after InitializeComponent.

Comment: [`FallbackValue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingbase.fallbackvalue.aspx) is used when binding fails (e.g. when `DataContext == null`). It's indeed often used as *design-time default value*, but it has also usage during run-time (e.g. when converter explicitly returns `UnsetValue`)

Answer (score 2):

A simple way to prevent a binding being cleared when changing bound property value in code, is to use `TwoWay` binding mode:

```
<DockPanel Name="panelControl"
           Visibility="{Binding MyViewModelProperty_IsVisible_ConvertedToVisibility,
                        Mode=TwoWay}">
```

I found this out the hard way, of course, lol.

Actually, using `TwoWay` mode does make sense if you have a reason for modifying a control's property directly (as opposed to modifying the bound property) - you would then want the bound property to reflect the change too.

By the way, instead of binding to a property of type `Visibility` it is better to use bind to a boolean and use a converter like `BooleanToVisibilityConverter` as it decouples *ViewModel* from *View* even better:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter" />
</Window.Resources>

...

<DockPanel Name="panelControl"
           Visibility="{Binding MyViewModelProperty_IsVisible,
                        Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter},
                        Mode=TwoWay}">
```

*Yeah, I know this is an old question and has an accepted answer but I found no other answer offering this solution directly.*